# Sqlite Query Issue

Tags: java, sqlite, where-clause

Alright, so I'm trying to store data in Sqlite. So I'm trying to store the id of the user with the a "line". Yet, it seems that the where clause is failing me.

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='Fellixombc";
    ResultSet result = this.sqlStatement.executeQuery(query);
    int userId = 0;
    while(result.next()) {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
        userId = result.getInt("id");
        System.out.println(result.getString("username"));
    }
```

And true is not printing. Yet, if I remove the WHERE clause from the query, it will print out all of the usernames/id's fine, and of course "TRUE".

Am I missing something with Sqlite and it's syntax?

edit: Just to clarify there is a user in the Users column with the id of 1 and with the username Fellixombc
edit: So I took your guy's suggestion and tried prepare statement, heres my code now:

```
        PreparedStatement sqlStatement = this.sqlConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=?");
        sqlStatement.setString(1, "Fellixombc");
        ResultSet result = sqlStatement.executeQuery();
        int userId = 0;
        while(result.next()) {
            System.out.println("TRUE");
            userId = result.getInt("id");
            System.out.println(result.getString("username"));
        }
        result.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you want to store the username, correct?

Your current query will retrieve all information on relative to a username. It's what a SELECT query does, it retrieves.

If you need to create a new user, use:

```
INSERT INTO Users (username) Values ('Fellixombc');
```

I should tell you that you might need to provide more information in this query, depending on what other fields your Users table has.

EDIT:

In your select statement, you have an open single quote.

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='Fellixombc"
```

should be

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='Fellixombc'"
```

To avoid issues with SQL injection, consider the [prepareStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29) function.

Comment: hmm, oddly enough that still doesn't work when I close that single quote, any other ideas? And yes, I will use prepareStatement but first I would like to get this to work. And also: I'm trying to retrieve the id of the user, I'm not inserting anything. edit: I'm trying to retrieve the id of Fellixombc, which should be 1.

Comment: If you remove your where condition, do you get any records at all?

Comment: yes, I get my one record, which is the record holding Fellixombc and the id of 1.

Comment: FOr the heck of it, if you reverse your condition, 'WHERE Id = 1', do you still get your record?

Comment: Yes, that works. So I just wonder if there is a field datatype wrong. The data type for the field username is 'Text', should I change it to varchar instead?

Comment: No, SQLite types are weird, there's no real varchar, text is fine. Let me meditate on this. Did you double check the spelling? Otherwise, there could be an encoding issue, if your code is say in UTF8 and your db in ASCII. Just a thought.

Comment: Aha! There was an extra white space at the end of Fellixombc in the database entry. Though, it's still not working. Note: I tried my query inside of my sqlite query browser, and it worked, so I wonder if my db is in ascii.

Comment: woops, nvm, it worked. There was a white space in my name after the last character =/ Anyways, thank you for your time! At least I learned something from this: check for whitespace, use prepared statements to avoid sql injection. Thank you, once again!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a trim on your username field. Its possible there's a spurious space somewhere in the data thats causing your where clause to fail.

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE trim(username) ='Fellixombc'"
```

Also, agree with @MPelletier. You should definitely be using PreparedStatements.

Comment: Alright, also, username isn't a variable I'm trying to access, its a field I'm trying to access. Or did I just completely misunderstood you? Anyways, look @OP

Comment: @Fellixombc -- yes. I realize its a field in the sqllite database table called Users. You can use the trim() function in a query. See here -- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html .. The whitespace at the end of your name could be causing the mismatch.

Comment: Oh ok, well, it turned out to be an issue with the actual record =/ Anyways, sorry for being so oblivious towards you! I appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you notice, thats what my answer was implying -- that there were extra whitespaces at the end of the record :-) ..